# How to use static variable to remember last passed argument

Tags: c++, c

I have a function that receives an argument and does something. I want to check if the parameter is different than the last call to the function. As far I understood, I can easily use a golbal variable or global static (only in the current translation  unit). But is it possible to achieve the same thing using static variable inside the function (I would argue it is more readable and the code will be cleaner if I would have many similar functions).

The problem is what should I init the variable so I make sure the next time I Call the function it works?

```
// Scenario A
void foo(uint16_t stuff) {

    // Error: Obviously lastStuff is not declared yet!
    if(lastStuff != stuff) {
        doStuff();
    }

    static uint16_t lastStuff = stuff;

} 

// Scenario B
void foo(uint16_t stuff) {

    static uint16_t lastStuff = stuff;        

    // lastStuff will always be equal to stuff
    if(lastStuff != stuff) {
        doStuff();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Initialize it to something it should never be passed in as - like null or -1. Then in your conditional check to see if it's null or -1. If so, it's the first time the function was called.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? There are C++ solutions that can't be used in C, like `std::optional`.

Comment: @Barmar For both...I have the problem solved now thanks to Sergey, I look std::optional on my own :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scenario `B` is almost correct, but you need a way to see if you had at least one execution or not. You can do it with `std::optional` or a simple boolean flag - I will go with the flag for simplicity:

```
// Scenario B
void foo(uint16_t stuff) {

    static uint16_t lastStuff;
    static bool last_inited = false;

    // lastStuff will be impossible value on the first execution
    if(lastStuff != stuff || !last_inited) {
        last_inited = true;
        doStuff();
    }
    lastStuff = stuff;
}
```

What it will do is to initialize static bool variable to `false` on the first function execution, and than it will be set to `true` and will remain true for all next executions.

Comment: The problem is, as you said, in this case all values are possible (it is a 16 bit register so anything is possible). What do you mean by two variables? can you please give an example?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a separate flag variable to see if the funcition was called at least once:

```
void foo(uint16_t stuff) {

    static int firstTime = 1;
    static uint16_t lastStuff = 0;        

    // lastStuff will always be equal to stuff
    if(!firstTime && (lastStuff != stuff)) {
        doStuff();
    }    

    lastSutff = stuff;
    firstTime = 0;
}
```